I wish Monica pass this exam…
Thank you all who have helped me with my first question. Today I have one more which has sparked a heated discussion among my colleagues.
How to say the following correctly?
Imagine a situation. Monica, a 20-year-old student, is a bundle of nerves on the eve of a super difficult exam. Over the family dinner her granny says: "I wish Monica pass this exam with flying colours tomorrow!" to encourage her.
Should we say: "I wish Monica pass..." or "I am wishing Monica to pass..." or any other way?
Having the name of Monica in this wish is obligatory.

I give Monica all my best wishes for her exam tomorrow.

Thanks, Michael.

I hope Monica passes her exam with flying colours (?)

It's not very idiomatic to use wish in this exact context (we tend to use it for unlikely / impossible "wanted future / alternative reality situations" like I wish I was a millionaire). What native Anglophones say here is "I hope Monica passes her exam".

It's not clear that Monica is at the table while her grandmother is speaking. If she is there, it would it be more natural to say: "I'm sure you'll pass / I hope you pass with flying colours!"

You, or your colleagues, may be confusing two kinds of wish.
There's the 'magical' wish, where you name something you would like to happen in a situation which is supposed to guarantee that it will come true, like dropping a coin in a 'wishing well'. Granny might say "I wish for Monica to pass her exam with flying colours" (only wishes of  this kind are traditionally supposed to be made silently).
Then there's the kind where you wish someone a happy birthday, or, as Michael says, give them your best wishes for some coming event.

I wish that something happens.

I wish that she passes the exam.

I wish for someone to do something.

I wish for her to pass the exam.

To say that you are wishing for someone to pass with flying colors implies that you think they may need some luck to do so. (See Kate Bunting's remark about making such wishes silently.) So it's not actually an encouraging way to phrase it.  It is not "confidence boosting" -- unless they believe in the power of granny wishes.
As a sort of miniature speech after dinner:

Here's wishing Monica well on her exam tomorrow!

That would mean "Monica is in my thoughts and I want her to succeed. I understand tomorrow is an important day for her."

Thanks! One last question: when you say that wishes of this kind are supposed to be made silently do you mean that they are similar to, say, making wishes on the New Year's night when we focus on smth and pronounce the wish silently, right?

What is wished for is not the reality at present. Something you have in your heart, that you fervently would like to happen, can be kept to yourself or spoken aloud.  When the wish involves another person, you must take care when speaking the wish aloud in their presence.  For example, if you say to a child "I wish you would do well in school" the meaning is not merely that you fervently want the child to do well in school, but that you believe they are not doing well, or well enough, now. What is wished for is not the reality at present.

But when we "wish someone something",  the meaning is different. I wish you a happy birthday.  It means "May this day be happy for you!"
